# Help with Ghostscript 8.15.3 in SUSE 10

Tags: ghostscript

I'm trying to upgrade a Suse 7.3 server to Suse 10 Server running Ghostscript.  The older server has GS v6.51 and the newer version has v8.15.3.  My older server receives LPR print jobs from a Windows printer configured as a Apple Color LaserWriter 12/600 and we are trying to upgrade to a HP Color LaserJet 9500 PS driver that is Windows 2008 R2 certified due to workstation upgrades. I have the newer server converting documents with the Apple driver but if I use the HP driver, it crashes with:

```
%%[ Error: configurationerror; OffendingCommand: setpagedevice ]%%
```

I have searched google but can't find a resolution. I'm at a loss on what to try next.

**[Update]** I tried printing just a notepad file with a simple HELLO in the text and no graphics.  The same error pops up if I use the newer v8.15 Ghostscript and the HPCLJ driver.  BUT, if I send that same job to the older v6.51 Ghostscript using the HPCLJ driver it converts.  How can I see what configuration the older driver is using because it converts the PS to PDF without error?  Why does it not fail on the older converter?

[Resolved] Drop HP and use a Xerox Phaser 6120 PS driver for wonderful results.  Once I was able to get my other admin to allow the change it worked fantastic.

Comment: @Dale Menken: Your clients' OS versions are amongst the most modern you can think of (Win 2008 R2). They are using one of the newest HP Color LaserJet 9500 PS drivers available. How can you expect that a print server running one of the oldest Ghostscript versions available would work flawlessly with this print data stream?

Comment: @Dale Menken: This must have been the *ESP Ghostscript 8.15.3* fork of Artifex' Ghostscript that you have on your SuSE 10. It's from ca. September 2006.

Answer (score 1):

That's a PostScript error, Ghostscript is telling you that the PostScript program has requested a feature which is incompatible with the Ghostscript device you are using.

Without knowing how you are using Ghostscript (the command line) and seeing at least the header of the PostScript job, I can't really offer any concrete suggestions. Can you have the user print a blank page, and if that fails, post the file somewhere public, along with a GS invocation ?

By the way, that's still a very old version of Ghostscript.....